# php password encryption, key include

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

I am using hash_hmac to hash my passwords with a key in a text file (protected by htaccess) like so..

```
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha512', $p, file_get_contents(folder/keys.txt'));
```

It works fine and all, but now I am wondering if I should instead have my key in a .php script and include that instead of file_get_contents.

which method would be more secure and faster?

Comment: whats the reason for not using a database?  Just wondering...

Comment: Remove it from the Document Root Entirely ....

Comment: thanks Baba, I have not ever done that before. better see if my host allows that. Am I right in thinking that an include would perform faster than a file_get_contents

Comment: @FredTurner in the comment of d0mmmy's answer you say that you are using "_bcrypt, salted, and blowfish_", but your code example in this question is not anything like that. Can you clarify this a bit?

Comment: @user1615903 I was only posting code relevant to my question, which was my method of "importing" my txt file. That is only a small chunk of the entire process

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to hash with a certain key at all? You should never have to decode a users password.

Why not just used something like md5() and then when testing if password is correct (for example at login just just do:

```
if (md5($input) == $storedPassword) {
//correct
} else {
//incorrect
}
```

Comment: md5?...may as well store it in plain text. I am using bcrypt, salted, and blowfish

Comment: Don't advise to use md5: sha512 is way more secure and also a one-way hashing algorithm

Comment: he's using sha512 which is more secure than md5. why you have no salt if you give md5 as example.